# Connecting PCB to Bus bars and assembly

Tags: power, pcb, current, pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I am working on a project that have to carry high amount of current (200A continuous). Therefore it is necessary to provide bus bars to the PCB, that would support passing it through circuit. I would like to pass finally version of this board into the assembly, but I am not sure how it is going with bus bars, that I would like place there.

1. Is it possible to mount bus bars to PCB in assembly?
2. Maybe there is any alternative solution instead of bus bars? Are you aware of any other, like specialized power PCB with local thicker copper? Of course - looking for low cost of service.
3. How about screwing bus bars to PCB instead of soldering? Would it work properly?

Comment: Please be aware that shopping questions are off-topic and will result in your question being closed. It's explained in the [Help].

Comment: I think it is PCB assembly related

Comment: Sure, but "*Do you know any assembly company that would support placing bus bars on the PCB?*" is a direct product / service shopping question and that's not allowed. I'm just pointing it out so you can edit to avoid having your question closed.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know any assembly company that would support placing bus bars on the PCB?

I think most companies will do special requests, they may charge extra. If your thinking of soldering the bus bars to the PCB then if its relativity manufacurable then some will, if its not then they may say "we aren't comfortable doing this process".

> Maybe there is any alternative solution instead of bus bars? Are you
> aware of any other, like specialized power PCB with local thicker
> copper? Of course - looking for low cost of service.

There are companies that I've seen that do thick copper (3oz or greater). There are also some that [integrate bus bars into PCB's](https://www.taiyo-technologies.jp/solution/pcb-en/high-current/bus-bar-embedded) these come with associated costs. But if you want to keep the copper within a 60C rise above ambient with 200Z you'd need a trace that is 5oz and 2" wide at least.
A 3oz trace would need to be 3" wide.

Another thing is this will be a challenge to solder, as during assembly the PCB will struggle to warm up to the temperature to melt solder.

> How about screwing up bus bars to PCB instead of soldering? Would it
> work properly?

It should, as a designer, calculate and keep the resistance low. If you need to use multiple fasteners parallel them to keep the resistance low.